# MS Access VBA - Detect active format condition on an sub form record

Tags: vba, ms-access, conditional-formatting

When I click on a record in a sub form, I would like to determine which conditional format has been applied to the record.

Refer to image below.

The coloured textbox is named txt_status_colr.

Complex conditional formatting criteria decides the background colour (blue, brown, green).

When I click a given record I would like to determine the conditional backcolor rather than have to re-examine the criteria (that created the colour) in the first place.

In other words, I want to establish which format condition is active for the selected record.

I want to do something like this:

```
For i = 0 To Me.txt_status_colr.FormatConditions.count - 1
    If Me.txt_status_colr.FormatConditions(i).ACTIVE = True Then
      Debug.Print Me.txt_status_colr.FormatConditions(i).BackColor
    End If
Next
```

Obviously the .ACTIVE property in code sample above does not exist but it demonstrates what I would like to achieve.

[image: Sub form record with conditional formatting]

Comment: I really don't think that can be done. I think will have to evaluate the data.

Comment: If this were Excel, could be done https://excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/338-Get-Displayed-Cell-Color-(whether-from-Conditional-Formatting-or-not)